# Which are the cases that make it hard to distinguish between code and data?

Tags: reflection, rebol, red, homoiconicity

It is said code is data (and vice versa, i.e. homoiconic) in Rebol and Red.
Also, it is said that it's impossible to distinguish between the two.
My understanding is that there are 2 cases here:

1. Determine *with certainty* **code** from a mix of code and data
2. Determine *with certainty* **data** from a mix of code and data

*mix of code and data* is my name for what outsiders would usually call Rebol code, and experienced Rebol programmers say is data (there is no code, only data)

### Motivation

The code vs data distinction make some features in programming languages easier.
For e.g. disassembly was mentioned (sbcl has the `disassemble` function).

## Question

What are examples of these problematic cases?

### context:

[from chat on March 15, 2017 3:32 PM](https://gitter.im/red/help?at=58c91845dd08b4b859d361a6): (emphasis mine)

> > Didec: You forget that there is no code in Redbol, only data.
> >
> > Maximvl: well, it's same for CL and SBCL complies everything down to native code and since code = data, one can say that there is no data, only code
>
> It is **not** the same in Lisp languages, there *is* a distinction between "code" and "data" [in Lisp], as code has to start with a *call*. Redbol has no such restriction on code, which makes it very different.

also:

> Moreover, contexts and dynamic binding make it way more flexible, but at the same time, *translating directly to low-level assembly code, like in your CL example, is not possible*.

*Aside: Does this mean Rebol is more homoiconic than Lisp?*

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, there is no "mix of code and data" from which to get code from: it is all data. This is the same as in (untyped) lambda calculus, where values are functions, E.g. true is `\x \y -> x`, false is `\x \y -> y` and if is `\bool \then \else -> bool then else` etc

Comment: "Does this mean Rebol is more homoiconic than Lisp" => no.

Comment: @Caleth you can say that, but isn't it useful sometimes to make the distinction? ;) Alternatively you could say from your example it is all code/functions, no data :p

Comment: Whether something is code or data depends on the context. There may be times where you can lock down the meaning for a value, but only in context. `Load` a file of Red values and it's just data. `Do` that same file and Red will interpret it. Process it with another tool and it's data again.

Comment: @GreggIrwin so if there is `do` or `reduce` it is certainly *code* then? (a.k.a. case 1?)

Comment: @GreggIrwin that at least partly answers the opposite of my question (what makes it easy) `do`, `reduce`, `func` is almost always followed by code. Should that be a separate question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one:

```
[q]
```

Outsiders will recognize the Q function and see this as a code block, while Rebol insiders will know that it must be data because Q is only called from the top level of the interpreter.